# Can't get login input element with selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I was trying to some selenium program but now I'm stuck at logging in.

- **Here is code** => https://pastebin.com/ykTcd1rb
- When code execute last line of code (`username = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'Login')`) I get an error (`selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="Login"]"}`)
- Here is Element which i trying to get `<input aria-invalid="false" type="text" class="form-control" name="Login" id="Login" required="">`

Please Help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see, this command `more = driver.find_element(By.ID, "dropdownTopRightMenuButton")` can't be executed since that element is not visible.
Also, it's not a good idea to use hardcoded sleeps. `WebDriverWait` `expected_conditions` should be used instead.
The following code worked for me:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

webdriver_service = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=webdriver_service)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

url = "https://portal.librus.pl/rodzina/synergia/loguj"

driver.get(url)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "cookieBoxClose"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.login-before-btn"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[name='email']"))).send_keys("my_username")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[name='password']"))).send_keys("my_password")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[type='submit']"))).click()
```

This, of cause, failed to login because I have no valid credentials, but with correct credentials this should work